# ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined after update Axios@1.3.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs, react-typescript

I had been using Axios v1.2.2 in my project without issues and I decided to update Axios to v1.3.1, after that my app continues running as before, however, all my tests started to fails... ALL OF THEM!!

Some package versions that I'm using:

```
"axios": "^1.3.1",
"@jest/globals": "^29.4.1",
"@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
"@testing-library/dom": "^8.20.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
```

This is the error that I'm getting in all my tests:

```
 Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

    > 1 | import { AxiosError } from "axios";
        | ^
      2 |
      3 | class UnknownResponseFormat<T = unknown, D = unknown> extends AxiosError<T, D> {
      4 |   static readonly ERR_UNKNOWN_RESPONSE_FORMAT = "ERR_UNKNOWN_RESPONSE_FORMAT";
```

I also found some workarounds for this on the internet, some things like this...

```
if (typeof global.TextEncoder === "undefined") {
  const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require("util");
  global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
  global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
}
```

...but it doesn't work either.

PLEASE! SOMEBODY HELP ME!

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered same problem. I think problem appered from version 1.3.0, I've checked version 1.2.6 and it's ok.

I didn't see any breaking changes in [release notes](https://github.com/axios/axios/releases), so I created support/question [issue on github project](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5529).

I hope I will find solution or they will answer me.

If you need quick workaround, just **change axios version to 1.2.6 in your package.json file**. If any your dependencies are fetching axios in >= 1.3.0 use **override** option, ex.:

```
...
"overrides": {
    "your-dependecy-package": {
        "axios": "1.2.6"
    }
},
...
```

Comment: Yeah! they fixed it https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/5530
thank you @FilipBaszak for creating the issue
the solution is install the version >= 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to add the following lines before running axios to resolve a similar issue (have never used axios before):

```js
import { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } from 'text-encoding';

global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
```

Comment: Nice! But for me the solution was just install the version 1.3.2 or higher, in this version the issue is gone